# $a^3b - ab^3 = c^3d - cd^3$ integer parametric solution

Tags: number-theory

I would like to know if there is any known parametrization for equation $a^3b - ab^3 = c^3d - cd^3$, where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct positive integers. If there is no known paramatrization, the most general algebraic formula will also be helpful.

For example, equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$ has parametric solution $a = pr + qs$, $b = qr - ps$, $c = ps + qr$, $d = pr - qs$, where $p,q,r,s$ are integers.

Comment: Your expression factors $X^3Y-XY^3=XY\left(X+Y\right)\left(X-Y\right)$. For a given integer, you can look at its factors and see if any combinations take this form.

Comment: e.g. $30=2\times3\times5\times1=2\times3\times\left(3+2\right)\times\left(3-2\right)=2^{3}\times3-2\times3^{3}$.

Comment: I know about factorization method, but it is not what I want. I would like to know a formula.

Comment: The formula you cited is derived via factorising the equation. $\left(a+c\right)\left(a-c\right)=\left(d+b\right)\left(d-b\right)$ from this, you can conclude that $a+c=pq$, $a-c=rs$ and $d+b=pr$ and $d-b=qs$ rearranging for $a,b,c,d$ gives the parametrisation you mention. In your case it is more subtle, since the factors obey certain relations, like one factor must be the sum of two others, so it is more complex. Either way, you need to use factorisation to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Okay I understand, thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: A general number might not factor in the given way: for instance $10=2\times 5$ cannot be factored as $XY\left(X+Y\right)\left(X-Y\right)$ in any way, since there is no way to factor $10$ in this way - one of the factors must be $\pm 2$ the other $\pm 5$ which forces the others to be $\pm 1$ and you can eliminate cases. Your question amounts to answering when a number has two such factorisations, and this is quite tricky.